# Using Lagrange's Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

[image]

Let $S$ be the system shown in Figure. The rail is smooth and the prescribed force
$F(t)$ acts on the particle $P_2$ as shown. Gravity is absent. Find the Lagrange equations
for $S$.

Take generalised coordinates $x$, $θ$ as shown and let the corresponding generalised
forces be called $Q_x$, $Q_θ$. Then, since S has just two particles,

$$Q_x=F^S_1 \frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x}+F^S_2 \frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x}$$$$
Q_θ=F^S_1 \frac{\partial r_1}{\partial θ}+F^S_2 \frac{\partial r_2}{\partial θ}
$$

Where $F^S_1=0$ and $F^S_2=F(t)i$,

and $r_1=xi$, $r_2=(x+asinθ)i-(asinθ)k.$

The generalised forces are

$Q_x=0+(F(t)i)\dot(acos\theta i+asin\theta k)=(acos\theta)F(t).$

The Kinetic energy is $$T=m\dot{x}^2+(ma cos\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta}+\frac{1}{2}m \dot{\theta}^2$$

My question is, how did the kinetic energy become that equation? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with the position vector  to the masses (inertial components)

$$\vec R_{P1}=\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\vec R_{P2}=\vec R_{P1}+a\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin(\theta) \\
  -\cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

from here you obtain the velocity $~\vec{v}_{P1}~,\vec{v}_{P2}~$  and the kinetic energy

$$T=\frac m2 \,\vec{v}_{P1}\cdot\vec{v}_{P1}+\frac m2 \,\vec{v}_{P2}\cdot\vec{v}_{P2}$$